# co-authorship of publications

Tags: publications

How can I find all publications where I am listed as a co-author?  I have been assisting on a number of projects as a supervisor from the community and providing materials and information for the research projects which are to do with bush foods.  I know I have been listed as a co-author but need a list for another research grant.  The University is in WA.

Comment: "_How can I find all publications where I am listed as a co-author?_" You don't know what papers you wrote ?

Comment: Not my stuff to judge but I am "literally" curious how you do not know the papers in which you are involved. Does this mean that you want your PhD/post-docs to write papers for you and you are not concretely involved in these projects?

Comment: @Nobody: Thinking about this has me now wondering whether my [Erdős number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s_number) is 1 instead of a rather mundane 3, because maybe I co-authored a paper with Erdős back in the 1970s or 1980s and forgot about doing so. (Yes, I know there are several easy ways to check this -- [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_people_by_Erd%C5%91s_number) and [this](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/freetools/collab-dist) and [this](https://zbmath.org/collaboration-distance/).)

Answer (score 6):

It's an odd question, but let me give an answer ignoring the big elephant in the room that is mentioned in Nobody's comment to the question.

**[ORCID](https://orcid.org/):**
ORCID IDs are unique digital identifiers for authors, similar to what DOIs are for papers. If you have an ORCID ID, and this was provided during the submission process of any papers, ORCID will list these publications under your name.

**[Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.com/):**
If you have a Google Scholar account, it also provides a list of publications. Note that Google Scholar's algorithm of assigning papers has its problems, and, in my experience, tends to assign items (e.g., presentation slides that are online somewhere) as publications to your profile. I also assume that it will have issues if your name is not unique. Note that unlike with ORCID, you don't need to have had an account at the time of publishing to add publications to your profile.

**Your memory/email:** If you are author on a manuscript, you will have (i) agreed to do so in communications with your co-authros, and (ii) had some sort of communication from the journal in which a paper if published, even if you were not the submitting author.